# dynamical plotting in Spyder freezing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spyder

I am trying to make a framework that is dynamically replotting the data using matplotlib.
However, every time I run the code, instead of updating the plot the plotting window stop responding until the code is done and then plot the final figure.

Is in a "feature" of Spyder, or I wrote something wrong? Is there any workaround so it will actually work?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time as t

def read_data():
    #retrieve the data, whatever

def update_plot(ax):
    time, hw = read_data()
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(time, hw)

fig_hw = plt.figure()
ax_hw = fig_hw.add_subplot(111)

plt.ion()

for i in range(100):    
    update_plot(ax_hw)
    plt.draw()
    t.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `time.sleep()` is a bad idea when working with GUI elements like the matplotlib plotting window. It literally lets the application sleep, resulting in an unresponsive (freezing) window. Use `plt.pause()` instead.